# Fazer upload de foto com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

Preciso pegar uma foto e ao pressionar o botão esta foto seja enviada para o meu servidor para então eu salvar no meu banco em base 64, só não consigo pegar a foto e converter para *Buffer*. Meu código:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
  .module('meetClass')
  .controller('NovaFotoController', NovaFotoController);

/** @ngInject */
function NovaFotoController($scope) {

  $scope.pular = function(){
    console.log("Pula")
  }

  $scope.cadastraFoto = function(){

  }

}
})()
```

Html

```
    <div class="divContentLogin">
    <form action="">
        <h3 style="color:#ffffff">Cadastrar Foto</h3>
        <div layout="column" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="inputsDadosLogin">
                <input mdInput type="file" id="fotoPerfil" class="colorInput" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="pular()">Pular</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="cadastraFoto()">Cadastrar</md-button>    
    </form>
</div>
```

Se tiver algum jeito de a partir deste input pegar esta foto carregada converter para *Buffer* vai me ajudar muito, ou então alguma outra solução alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Voce deve usar o formData no service do angularJS para isso, verifique se sua api esta preparada para receber requisições em formData

Primeiro chame a classe FormData do JS

```
var fd = new FormData();
```

Depois vc vai fazer um form encima dos campos que voce vai enviar

```
 for (var key in fields) {
   if (fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     fd.append(key, fields[key]);

   }
 }
```

Depois você vai enviar para a sua api , o 'fd' é o formData completo com a imagem e dos campos que você enviar junto

```
return $http.post('routeAPI', fd, {
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
});
```